# Bazel Maven migration Transitive Dependencies Scope

Tags: bazel

I am trying to use the `generate_workspace` on one of the project which has deps and transitive dependencies. Once the`generate_workspace.bzl` has been generated and I copied it to the WORKSPACE and followed the instruction in the bazel docs. Though I see the deps and their transitive deps listed in the `generate_workspace.bzl` my project during java_library phase is not able resolve transitive deps.. when I import the same project in IDEA I don't see the jars correctly loaded.

My doubt is for the deps I see the  generate_workspace.bzl is adding its transitve deps as `runtime_deps` which means they are available only during runt`enter code here`ime

I have created gist of all the files here 
https://gist.github.com/kameshsampath/8a4bdc8b22d85bbe3f243fa1b816e464

Ideally in my maven project I just need https://gist.github.com/kameshsampath/8a4bdc8b22d85bbe3f243fa1b816e464#file-src_main_build-L8-L9, though generate_workspace.bzl has resolved rightly i thought its enough if my src/main/BUILD looks like

```
java_binary(
      name = "main",
      srcs = glob(["java/**/*.java"]),
      resources = glob(["resources/**"]),
      main_class = "com.redhat.developers.DemoApplication",
      # FIXME why I should import all the jars when they are transitive to spring boot starter
      deps = [
          "//third_party:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_actuator",
          "//third_party:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_web",
            ],
)
```

But sadly that gives lots of compilation errors as transitive deps are not getting loaded as part the above declaration. eventually I have to define like how I did in the `https://gist.github.com/kameshsampath/8a4bdc8b22d85bbe3f243fa1b816e464#file-src_main_build`

src_main_build is BUILD file under package src/main/BUILD
third_party_BUILD is the BUILD under package third_party/BUILD

Comment: I think a snippet would go a long way here. Also, do you see any usage of "exports"?

Comment: @Ittai added the code snippets and link to gist

Answer (score 1):

Bazel expects you to declare all your direct dependencies. I.e. if you directly use a class from jar A, you need to have it in your direct dependencies.

What you are looking for is a deploy jar. This is a bit hacky but you can actually do it that way (in `third_party/BUILD`):

```
java_binary(
    name = "org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_actuator_bin",
    main_class = "not.important",
    runtime_deps = [":org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_actuator"], )

java_import(
    name = "springframework_actuator",
    jars = [":org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_actuator_bin_deploy.jar"], 
)
```

This will bundle all dependencies except the neverlink one in a jar (the `_deploy.jar`) and reexpose it.

Comment: Damien, can't he just use "deps" and then iterate through a few warnings from strict-deps? That will pass him through the few hurdles he needs transitively but will still give him a cleaner dependency graph

Comment: Damien, got error `ERROR: /Users/kameshs/MyLabs/bazel/bazel-demos/spring-boot-bazel-demo/src/main/BUILD:7:14: in deps attribute of java_binary rule //src/main:main: java_binary rule '//third_party:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_web
_bin' is misplaced here (expected cc_binary, cc_library, genrule, genproto, java_import, java_library, java_proto_library, java_lite_proto_library, proto_library, sh_binary or sh_library) and '//third_party:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_web_bin' does not have mandatory providers: 'link_params' or 'java_common.provider'.`

Comment: Kamesh: can you give the content of your build files? Ittai: yes he could and should to get a clean graph but he want to be able to just import 2 jars...

Answer (score 0):

An update: [`rules_jvm_external`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external) is the officially maintained ruleset by the Bazel team to fetch and resolve artifacts transitively.

You can find the example for Spring Boot [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/blob/master/examples/spring_boot/WORKSPACE). The declaration in the WORKSPACE file looks something like this:

```
load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.1.3.RELEASE",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.1.3.RELEASE",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.1.3.RELEASE",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.1.3.RELEASE",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.3.RELEASE",
        "org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE",
        "org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.5.RELEASE",
        "org.springframework:spring-test:5.1.5.RELEASE",
        "org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.5.RELEASE",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com",
    ]
)
```